# How to deep copy an NSIndexPath?

Tags: objective-c, nsindexpath

I want to save a copy of a NSIndexPath object for later use. Then, I want so overwrite the original object. As `copy` only increments the retain count of the object, how can I make a deep copy of the original index path?

```
...
NSIndexPath *originalIndexPath = [tappedIndexPath copy]; // need to make a deep copy here
tappedIndexPath = ...;
...
// need the original index path here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not exactly clear.  If you need to save this for later use in another class, you should try the two methods below.

You can not directly save the NSIndexPath in the NSUserDefaults.  However, you can use NSKeyedArchive and NSKeyedUnarchiver to help you do this.

http://gordiychuk.co.uk/2012/02/10/how-to-save-nsindexpath-to-nsuserdefaults/

I'm not sure exactly what you need to this with the NSIndexPath.  I did this I just passed the NSIndexPath through the init method when created my UIViewController.  I needed to know which row the user selected in another class.

For example:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil 
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil 
   initWithNSIdexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Do something indexPath
}
```

Comment: I need it in order to do some modifications to a `UITableViewCell` later. I try to pass it to `[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: originalIndexPath]`.

Comment: @Norbert use the link I gave you, this stores it in the NSUserDefaults and you can retrieve it anytime you want.

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding about the difference between objects and variables. Storing the index path in the user defaults is totally pointless here.

Comment: @omz: I actually archived it and then passed the NSData object directly to another method, I didn't store it permanently.

Comment: Still, it's pointless. You don't have to copy the object at all, because you couldn't modify it anyway. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: @omz just because you think it is pointless is irrelevant.  He asked how to save it, and I gave him an answer to save the NSIndexPath.  The point of this site is to ask questions, and get answers not opinions.

Comment: @Vikings So, he's archiving an `NSIndexPath` to an `NSData` object (probably using `NSKeyedArchiver`), to pass it directly to another method without storing it anywhere (e.g. the user defaults). Can you tell me what this actually achieves?

Answer (score 2):

As `NSIndexPath` is immutable anyway, it doesn't matter whether the copy is deep or shallow. In fact, a deep copy would be a waste of memory.

Regarding your example: For what you want to do, you don't need to copy the index path at all. When you assign another index path object to `tappedIndexPath` (in the second line), that doesn't affect `originalIndexPath` at all. At the end of your snippet, `originalIndexPath` will still point to the exact same object as before.

Comment: +1. To put it another way for Norbert: the only reason that "`copy` only increments the retain count" is because it is indistinguishable from actually making a copy. If there were a distinction, then `copy` could not be optimized to just retain.